# Why my script is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

When i am going to run this code i tested code working well, but my expected is not showing . it only showing [object XMLDocument] in every textbox. My controller for searching data from database is...

```
public string Search(string id=null)
        {
            string[] ci = new string[9];
            //return "Artistry";

            string cn = null;
            cn = Request.QueryString["id"];
            if (cn != null)
            {
                ClientInfo c = db.SingleOrDefault<ClientInfo>("where CName='" + cn + "'");
                if (c != null)
                {
                    ci[0] = c.CId.ToString();
                    ci[1] = c.CName;
                    ci[2] = c.CCName;
                    ci[3] = c.Address;
                    ci[4] = c.Email;
                    ci[5] = c.Fax;
                    ci[6] = c.Country;
                    ci[7] = c.PhoneNo.ToString();
                    ci[8] = c.PostalCode.ToString();
                    return ci[2];
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
            else
                return null;
             //*/
        }
```

My JavaScript Code is used for showing data in textboxes ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CName').blur(function () {
            var v = $('#CName').val();
            var url = "/Clients/Search/" + v;
          //  alert("Test : " + url);
            $.get(url, function (data, status) {
                $("#CId").val(data);
                $("#CCName").val(data);
                $("#Address").val(data);
                $("#Email").val(data);
                $("#Fax").val(data);
                $("#Country").val(data);
                $("#PhoneNo").val(data);
                $("#PostalCode").val(data);
                //alert("Test : " + data + " Status :" + status);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

My database sql query..

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [CId]
      ,[CName]
      ,[CCName]
      ,[PhoneNo]
      ,[Fax]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Address]
      ,[PostalCode]
      ,[Country]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[ClientInfo]
```

Comment: My alert result in javascript code is- Test : [object XMLDocument] Status :success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the data from the 'data'-object by index.
Adding the index of the values behind the data object should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CName').blur(function () {
            var v = $('#CName').val();
            var url = "/Clients/Search/" + v;
          //  alert("Test : " + url);
            $.get(url, function (data, status) {
                $("#CId").val(data[0]);
                $("#CCName").val(data[2]);
                $("#Address").val(data[3]);
                $("#Email").val(data[4]);
                $("#Fax").val(data[5]);
                $("#Country").val(data[6]);
                $("#PhoneNo").val(data[7]);
                $("#PostalCode").val(data[8]);
                //alert("Test : " + data + " Status :" + status);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because data is an object and you are setting data.toString() into the values of the input. It does not magically get mapped. You need to pull the data out of the object that is being returned.

Comment: can you give me a sample..boss

Comment: I do not know what your data looks like to give you an example. Put what is exactly returned from the server in your question and I could point you in the right direction.

Comment: I put a database structure in my question...is this helpful?